# The OAuth2 API for obtaining tokeninfo (https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo) occasionally experiences the issue of missing the "sub" field

Tags: oauth-2.0, scope, google-play-games

We have recently encountered some failures while verifying Google tokens. All of these failures occur when the response received from the OAuth2 API (https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo) does not contain the "sub" field. Please assist us in resolving this issue.

This is the response we received:

```
{
 "aud": "919759----------apps.googleusercontent.com",
 "expires_in": "3598",
 "access_type": "offline", 
 "exp": "1696667490",
 "azp":
 "919759---------apps.googleusercontent.com",
 "scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/games_lite"
}
```

We are using Google Play Games services on Android to log in and obtain an AuthCode.

```
GamesSignInClient gamesSignInClient = PlayGames.getGamesSignInClient(this);
gamesSignInClient
  .requestServerSideAccess(OAUTH_2_WEB_CLIENT_ID, /* forceRefreshToken= */ false)
  .addOnCompleteListener( task -> {
    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
      String serverAuthToken = task.getResult();
      // Send authentication code to the backend game server to be
      // exchanged for an access token and used to verify the player
      // via the Play Games Services REST APIs.
    } else {
      // Failed to retrieve authentication code.
    }
});
```

Then we send the AuthCode to the server to obtain an access token.

Finally, we retrieve token information using the OAuth2 API (https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo), and the typical response is as follows:

```
{
 "azp": "1615072----------apps.googleusercontent.com",
 "aud": "1615072----------apps.googleusercontent.com",
 "sub": "1020----------3970",
 "scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/games_lite https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile openid",
 "exp": "1696654678",
 "expires_in": "3557",
 "email": "zh----------@gmail.com",
 "email_verified": "true",
 "access_type": "offline"}
```

[Enabling Server-Side Access to Google Play Games Services](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/offline-access)